# Библиотека zxing.dll и разные уровни коррекции ошибок в QR-кодах

Tags: c#, qrcode

У меня есть приложение, которое создаёт qr-коды. Для этого я использую библиотеку zxing.dll. И я никак не могу понять, почему при изменении уровня коррекции ошибок, выходной qr код получается всегда одним и тем же, какой бы уровень я не поставил.
Очень может быть, что я что-то делают не так. Прошу посмотреть и указать на явную ошибку, если она тут есть.

```
QrCodeEncodingOptions options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
            {
                DisableECI = true,
                CharacterSet = "utf-8",
                Width = 250,//Изменение этих параметров отчётливо видно в результате
                Height = 250,
                Margin = 3,
                ErrorCorrection = ZXing.QrCode.Internal.ErrorCorrectionLevel.L, //А вот этот меняй не меняй, всё одно
            };

            QRCodeWriter qrEncode = new QRCodeWriter ( ); //создание QR кода
            if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty ( strPathToFileTXT ) )
                strRUS = "Текст не задан";
            else
            {
                if ( GetEncoding ( strPathToFileTXT ) == "Win-1251" )
                {
                    Encoding altEnc = Encoding.GetEncoding ( "windows-1251" );
                    using ( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader ( strPathToFileTXT, altEnc ) )
                    {
                        strRUS = sr.ReadToEnd ( );
                    }
                }
                else
                    strRUS = File.ReadAllText ( strPathToFileTXT );
            }
            if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty ( strRUS ) )
                strRUS = "Файл пуст";

            Dictionary<EncodeHintType, object> hints = new Dictionary<EncodeHintType, object> ( );    //для колекции поведений

            hints.Add ( EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "utf-8" );   //добавление в коллекцию кодировки utf-8
            BitMatrix qrMatrix = qrEncode.encode (   //создание матрицы QR
                strRUS,                 //кодируемая строка
                BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,  //формат кода, т.к. используется QRCodeWriter применяется QR_CODE
                300,                    //ширина
                300,                    //высота
                hints );                 //применение колекции поведений
            BarcodeWriter qrWrite = new BarcodeWriter ( );    //класс для кодирования QR в растровом файле
            qrWrite.Options = options;
            Bitmap qrImage = qrWrite.Write ( qrMatrix );   //создание изображения
            if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty ( strPathToImage ) )
                qrImage.Save ( strPathToImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp );//сохранение изображения
            if ( dClipboard )
                Clipboard.SetImage ( qrImage );
```

Answer (score 0):

Кажется я разобрался. 
Адекватно работает только если передать параметр уровня коррекции ошибок вот так:
hints.Add ( EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, "Q" );